# Track how many days in a case was in particular status through case history

Tags: apex

I have to find how many days was a case in Status open.

For that i am doing the query:

```
SELECT Id, NewValue, OldValue FROM CaseHistory WHERE Field = 'Status'
```

I am getting list of cases where oldvalue and newvalue are displaying, now how to populate this inside a custom field?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use formula fields to track the moment in which the Status start on a certain value and when it changes to something else. 2 fields will track that time and a third field can calculate the differences and that be displayed in your page layout.

You can use Tracking Field History as well, but that wouldn't allow you to get a field with the data you want.